# cannot convert Json in android studio

Tags: java, android, json

Trying to learn how to connect between php android studio with basic example json.
Has been two weeks and I'm trying to connect to various directories and always get errors .
That's why I want to learn a basic example then proceed

I get the exception:

```
> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script
> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

this is my main.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
        Button fetch;
        TextView text;
        EditText et;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            fetch= (Button) findViewById(R.id.fetch);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

            fetch.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
        {
            private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            InputStream is = null ;
            String result = "";
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching data...");
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                        task.this.cancel(true);
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                String url_select = "my site.php";

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    //read content
                    is =  httpEntity.getContent();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = "";
                    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result=sb.toString();
                    Log.e("result",result);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }

                return null;

            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

                // ambil data dari Json database
                try {
                    JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
                    Log.e("rannn",Integer.toString(Jarray.length()));
                    for(int i=0;i<Jarray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
                        //text_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                        Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        //get an output on the screen
                        //String id = Jasonobject.getString("id");
                        String name = Jasonobject.getString("name");
                        String db_detail="";

                        if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                            db_detail = Jasonobject.getString("quantity");
                            text.setText(db_detail);
                            break;
                        }
                        //text_1.append(id+"\t\t"+name+"\t\t"+password+"\t\t"+"\n");

                    }
                    this.progressDialog.dismiss();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.fetch : new task().execute();break;
            }

        }

    }
```

this is my json returned in result from the php when i run it in the browser.

```
{"name":"10","quantity":"50"}
```

and this is the result in log before i try parser.

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("4149455d59914a7942887c4bd71ed6dc");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="mysite.php?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Comment: Share the JSON you want to parse and the POJO!

Comment: `<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>< ...` is not a json string. it is *html*. What URL are you trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

The request you are posting is not returning JSON.

This is clearly obvious in your log:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value `<html><body>`

Debug your server and app to find out why you are not getting JSON